# IBM Websphere 6.1 start up with limited user access

Tags: websphere

I have successfully installed IBM websphere on my windows 7 machine as administrator user.
Now, when I am trying to run the server using limited access user login, it is exiting with message .
However, when I try to run it using administrative login, server runs successfully.
Since my user Id is of limited access, what needs to be done for starting successfully the server with user login.
Do I need to first create a profile associated with user login.
If yes, then how to create new user profile.

Comment: You should have installed WebSphere as non administrative user, and dont add profile to Windows services when you are creating it.

Comment: I have installed websphere as administrative user. However, when I am trying to install using non-administrative user, it is giving me error: "Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator". I have checked it on google and nowhere found any way out.

Comment: Try to create new profile using administrative user, but provide custom profile path, like c:\myprofiles (not in program files), and dont add profile to Windows services. Make sure your user has full control in that folder. This should allow you to start the server.

Answer (score 0):

Since IBM Websphere was installed as administrator user, its installation directory (c:/Program Files/IBM/Websphere/*) was not accessible by limited access user. Since log files were also in the same directory, system was not allowing to start the server.
Also, I needed admin access on my system for starting/stopping the server.
I got read-write access on the installation folder and then again tried to start server using command prompt (serverStatus.bat server1).
The server started successfully on ports 9060/9043.